# Extract Date from file name using Regex

Tags: c#, regex, string, datetime

I have the following structure for names:

```
GuidAsString/yyyy/MM/dd.zip
```

An example:

```
e1e2e854-e1cd-4980-83bb-2a0273f904aa/2018/11/18.zip
```

I would like to extract the date using regex. Regex is just not my thing.

**Update:** I am trying to do something like:

```
DateTime dateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(name, format, formatprovider)
```

and I am looking for the format. If you have a more elegant way that would be even better.

I would appreciate your help.

Comment: How can you have a slash in a file name?

Comment: @KlausGütter it appears to me the file name is `18.zip`, and `/2018/` + `/11/` are simply subfolders

Comment: @K.Dᴀᴠɪs: ahh, yes, makes sense

Comment: I am sorry I was not accurate. Please ignore that I wrote file name and consider it a string that I need to extract the date from. Thanx

Answer (score 2):

```
string input = @"e1e2e854-e1cd-4980-83bb-2a0273f904aa/2018/11/18.zip";
string pattern = @"/(\d+/\d+/\d+)";
var match = Regex.Match(input, pattern);
var date = DateTime.Parse(match.Groups[1].Value);
WriteLine(date.ToShortDateString());
// Prints: 18.11.2018
```

#### One-liner:

```
var date = DateTime.Parse(Regex.Match(@"e1e2e854-e1cd-4980-83bb-2a0273f904aa/2018/11/18.zip", @"/(\d+/\d+/\d+)").Groups[1].Value);
```

Comment: I am trying to do something like: DateTime dateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(name, format, formatprovider). I would appreciate if you could provide me with the format here :)

Comment: @AkramShahda Well, my first code (see in [edited](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/53360152/revisions)) extracts year, month and time separately. You can do with them whatever you want. :)

Comment: Thank you but what I really need is a one liner code to get there.

Comment: @AkramShahda Added one-liner 

Comment: As the filename format is fixed, using three capture groups wouldn't be better than capture all in one and then having to parse the date again?

Comment: @LuisColorado Where do you see *three* capture groups?

Comment: @JohnyL, I don't see them (in yours), I _suggested_ you to use three capture groups, as in `@"/(\d+)/(\d+)/(\d+)"`, to obtain the date fields separate in one shot.  This way, you'll get three strings (`2018`, `11` and `18`)

Comment: @LuisColorado In my [first version of code](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/53360152/1) I do this very thing. Then I altered code to capture all numbers since DateTime parser recognizes this pattern of string, so it's unnecessary to capture day, month and year separately.

Comment: You are ok, in javascript, but you can have a different environment (I have a javascript environment where `Date` is not the standard date, and I have had to modify this to be able to build a proper date)  resolving the problem with regex in one shot avoids this.  Suppose you migrate to a different environment, where the path element separator is not `/`.

Comment: @LuisColorado Beg your pardon, but did you pay attention to tags?

Comment: I didn't too, indeed tags specify `c#` :)

Comment: @LuisColorado It's OK 

Answer (score 2):

you could use to extract the date in string format with regex:

```
var st = "e1e2e854-e1cd-4980-83bb-2a0273f904aa/2018/11/18.zip";
var st1 = Regex.Match(st,@"\d{4}/\d{2}/\d{2}").Value;
```

st1 = "2018/11/18"
if you want to convert in date format use:

```
var date = DateTime.Parse(st1);
```

Comment: I am trying to do something like: DateTime dateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(name, format, formatprovider). I would appreciate if you could provide me with the format here :)

Comment: Why not using `"/(\\d+)/(\\d+)/(\\d+)"` and then use the three captured groups separately to build a date with the native con.  Why to parse the date again to separate the three fields?

Answer (score 0):

You easily find the solution with some string manipulation. You can use [`String.Split`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.split?view=netframework-4.7.2) method like;

```
var str = "e1e2e854-e1cd-4980-83bb-2a0273f904aa/2018/11/18.zip";
var year = str.Split('/')[1];
var month = str.Split('/')[2];
var day = str.Split('/')[3].Split('.')[0];
```

[image]

and you can parse your parts like;

```
var myDate = DateTime.ParseExact($"{year}{day}{month}",
                                  "yyyyddMM",
                                  CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Comment: Thank you but don't you think it is too much code for one simple purpose?

Comment: @AkramShahda You don't _need_ regex for that. Use just simple string manipulations. It is _not_ an expensive operation after all. This is just 5 lines of code. Is it really too much? Don't you think it is more readable than regex one? Your choice..

Comment: @SonerGönül, why don't use regex for that?  Do you think that using simple string manipulations (each requiring one pass through the data, at least) will be better than doing all in just one pass?  Do you actually think that using `.split()` three times on the same `String` will be more efficient than getting the three fields in one shot?  Do you know that there are more things than using `.split()` ???